# After clean installation of threshold 2 over windows 10 i couldnt connect to internet via wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet

It may sound ridiculous. When i am near to the WiFi modem i could not connect to internet but if i am away from the modem WiFi works fine and i could connect to internet.
I did a clean installation of threshold 2 over windows 10 and i could not connect to internet via WiFi . Ethernet is working fine. I am using dell 3521 laptop and all drivers are up to date. WiFi was working fine in windows 10. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.In my WiFi drivers advanced properties the value of 802.11b value was 20 MHz only i changed it to 20MHz/40MHz Auto. Now WiFi works perfectly